# Property to restrict resources requested by Application Master

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is there a property in Hadoop MRv2 (Yarn) which allows us to specifically manipulate the amount of resources (VCores and Heap Memory) for requested by the Application Master? Or the Application Master does evaluates the resources required dynamically (per application basis) and requests the corresponding resources for the containers?

Answer (score 0):

Below properties can be used to set VCors and Heap Memory for YARN Application master.

```xml
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>8192</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value> -Xmx6144m</value>
</property>
```

`yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts` should be less than 80% of `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb`

Comment: I agree with the above properties. But I encounter the problem where, even if I set these properties on one node with less values (1 core and 1 GB of memory) and the other node has been set to provide more resources (2 cores and 8 GB of Memory), for my application (which takes about 3 GB of memory for application master), the application master starts only on the second node and never starts on the first node. Can I control the amount of the RAM requested by the Application Master's Container?

Comment: Above properties are not specific to nodes, instead these are application specific, If you wanted to reduce the Heap of application master in order to run on first node, you need to reduce the heap utilization of yarn application master by setting up yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb in the application(These are application specific properties not node specific ).